# Using encodeURIcomponent and decoding it on server side

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, encodeuricomponent

I sent a url as a part of request parameter by using encodeURIcomponent to server like

```
  http://www.regis.edu/regisgpcd.asp?sctn=cpedcn&amp;p1=ap&amp;p2=EDFD&amp;p3=cd3Dcd&_=1332612418587
```

This is what server sees:

```
http://www.regis.edu/regisgpcd.asp?sctn=cpedcn&amp;p1=ap&amp;p2=EDFD&amp;p3=cd
```

albeit I had inserted it before to database again with encodeURIcomponent, I got an error that it could not be found in database.

This url in the format like below although I inserted it after the encodeURIcomponent again. I guess mysql converted it to regular kind before inserted it on the column.

```
 http://www.regis.edu/regisgpcd.asp?sctn=cpedcn&p1=ap&p2=EDFD&p3=cd
```

How can I solve that problem? Any idea?

This is my insert code:

```
$.ajax({
                    type : "GET",
                    url : '/tree/insertResult/?url=' + encodeURIComponent(url) + '&title=' + encodeURIComponent(title)+'&folder='+folderName+'&snippet='+encodeURIComponent(snippet),
                    cache : false,
                    success : function(res) {
                        if(res == "F")
                            notification("Operation Failed", "You have that bookmark in that folder!");
                        else{   
                            folderName = res;
                            notification("Operation Suceeded", "Bookmark has been created.");
                            updateFolderContent(url, title, folderName, snippet);//it is in _filetree_javascript.html.erb
                        }
                    },
                    error : function(x, y, z) {
                        alert(x.responseText);
                    }
                });
            }
```

This is my fetch code:

```
$.ajax({
                type : "GET",
                url : '/tree/deleteResult/?title='+encodeURIComponent(title)+"&url="+encodeURIComponent(url), 
                cache : false,
                success : function(res) {
                    if(res == "F") //if F is returned from server it means "There is a folder with same name"
                        notification("Operation Failed", "Bookmark cannot be deleted! Sorry :(");   
                    else
                        notification("Operation Succeed", "Bookmark've been deleted.");     
                        deleteResult(domObj);
                },
                error : function(x, y, z) {
                    alert(x.responseText);
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Try to set `cache:false` in your ajax settings object .

Comment: set to what? true or false...

Comment: What parameter/s of url, do you use to delete your records?

Comment: url is a regular url http:// bla bla

Comment: title is the title of a page like in search engine results

Comment: Hmm..My advice to you, when you insert a data (by ajax call) , look at your inserted data row in your database table. And when deleteing (by ajax call), look if 'title' and 'url' are same as stored before. Good luck.

Comment: In addition to @user1113426 's comment, make sure your server-side script (which we don't see here) uses the same escaping functions for DB inserts and selects (PHP for instance: do *all* SQL requests use the *same* mysql_real_escape_string() on their parameters ?). Anyway, MySQL doesn't convert anything unless you explicitly ask for it. Couldn't the difference come from the fact that you're looking at a phpMyAdmin display ? Then it may be because `&amp;` entities are converted _by the browser_ on phpMyAdmin's _webpage_ ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve that problem via decoding the string on server. I used CGI gem in rails

```
CGI::unescapeHTML(url)
```